# Can I delete files in the 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\LOG' folder?

Tags: windows-xp, sql-server

This is on my development machine, running Windows XP, and I don't run any production db's on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are just setup logs, yes you can delete them.